# Javascript not caching images

Tags: javascript, caching

I have a gif that i made in phototshop (a loading wheel) but i find that the way that i am using it (hiding and then displaying with css and over writing with javascript later on) is just too laggy to begin with, it really skips hard at the beginning. so i decided to cache the  image before i call it. so this is how i did it:

```
function preloadImages(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = array[i];
        preloadImages.list.push(img);
    } 
}

var imageURLs = [
    "loading.gif"
];
```

Which should work, if im not mistaken. But just in case i have also tried:

```
loading = new Image(60,60)
loading.src = "images/loading.gif"
```

which i pulled from a tutorial. 
Now when I implement this(currently the first one) and then call the image normally later on, it seemingly runs faster and i can see it in my cache. however being the skeptic i am i decided to put in an image that i never use in the HTML and see if it gets cached(as it should) but then never call it. so heres my new JS:

```
function preloadImages(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = array[i];
        preloadImages.list.push(img);
    } 
}

var imageURLs = [
    "loading.gif",
    "today.gif"
];
```

Notice i added in `today.gif` Now, if my understanding of caching is correct, this image should now be cached even though i never call it in my "raw" HTML correct? well its not. which makes me wonder if the loading gif was even cached or if my browser just decided to cooperate for a bit. any ideas? heres what the cache look like on reload after a fresh clear with the second javascript snippet in use:

[image: cache]

so the questions here are: Is it working even though the cache says it's not? Am i imagining things? Am i doing this correct/is my understanding of local cache correct? If not, could someone explain to me where im going wrong? cheers.

Comment: Can you check the "net" tab in your browser tools to see whether a request to the GIF is ever made?

Comment: Are you calling the preload function? `preloadImages(imageURLs);`

Comment: Throw an `alert('ASDF');` after the end of that `for` loop and see if it pops up. (The poor man's debugging method.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 there is the obvious request for loading.gif that is made but there is never a request for today.gif anywhere

Comment: Then maybe the browser is optimizing away calls for image elements that never get inserted into the DOM? Not sure what the state of the art here is. (If it's true, it would render most preloading mechanisms moot)

Comment: @DC_ im calling it in the javascript after i set up the function. is the the correct way to do it? looks like this: `preloadImages()`

Comment: @Nick If you're not passing an array of URLs to that function, it's not going to do anything.

Comment: @DC_ looks like: `preloadImages("images/loading.gif", "images/today.gif);` verbatim still no change, i had it like that at one point and it made no difference. im a bit new to javascript, but from my background in php this is correct.  im really struggling to understand why im not seeing progress in the cache

Comment: @Nick Try `preloadImages(["images/loading.gif", "images/today.gif"]);`. Currently you're missing closing quotes and not passing an array, but rather two separate strings as arguments.

Comment: @DC_ wow that did it, looks like it was my knowlede of javascript and not that of cache being called into play here, thank so much man, if you post that as an answer ill be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you define expects an array as an argument.

Try `preloadImages(["images/loading.gif", "images/today.gif"]);`. Currently you're missing closing quotes and not passing an array, but rather two separate strings as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing it incorrectly -

When creating image object inside your for loop, do it within a closure function or the previous object will gets overwritten by the last one, the nature of its being asynchronouse -

```
(function(i){
var img = new Image();
img.src= array[i];}(i))
```

also, your creating a list and pushing the object to it is totally useless!